# SQL pivot single to multiple column and multiple row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody help me with SQL using pivot?

I asked before this using numbers but not now im using it in a string format

For example I have a list of Names shown below with 1 column:

[image]

and I want the result to become this. the will limit 10 column only

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()` to generate a running sequence, and then, use modulus `%` to get the column and divide by 10 to get the row. Use `PIVOT()` to get the required result

```
select  *
from
(
    select  [Names],
            [row] = row_number() over (order by [Names]) / 10 + 1,
            [col] = (row_number() over (order by [Names]) - 1) % 10 + 1
    from    yourtable
) d
pivot
(
    max([Names])
    for col in ([1], [2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) p
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 10 = 0 then name end) as name_0,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 1 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 2 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 3 then name end) as name_3,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 4 then name end) as name_4,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 5 then name end) as name_5,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 6 then name end) as name_6,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 7 then name end) as name_7,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 8 then name end) as name_8,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 9 then name end) as name_9
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 10);
```

Note:  The ordering of the names in the result set is not guaranteed.  Each name will appear in one position.  If the ordering matters, then you need an additional column that specifies the ordering (and you can use that in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves your question using dynamic pivot and without sorting the data with select null

```
  declare @groups varchar(max) set @groups = (select count(0)/2 from Mytable )
    declare @columns varchar(max) set @columns = '' 
    select @columns =  coalesce(@columns + '[' + cast(col as varchar(MAX)) + '],', '') 
    FROM ( 
        select col from (
            select (row_number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)) - 1) % (@groups) + 1 as col
            from Mytable group by Names 
        ) t
        group by col
    ) m

    set @columns = left(@columns,LEN(@columns)-1) 
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max);
    set @SQLString = '
    
    select * from 
     ( 
    select Names, row/'+@groups+' +1 as row , col from (
        select  [Names],
                [row] = row_number() over (order by (SELECT NULL))+1 / '+@groups+' -1,
                [col] = (row_number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)) - 1) % '+@groups+' + 1
        from    Mytable
        ) x
    
      ) m
    PIVOT 
    (   MAX(Names) 
        FOR col in (' + @columns + ')
    ) AS  PVT'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```